# User context when accessing a file share in python using UNC

Tags: python

When I access a file share like this:

```
file_path_csv_ae = "//samba.acme.net/other/pv_compliance/adverse_events.csv"
file_path_csv_ing = "//samba.acme.net/other/pv_compliance/active_ingredients.csv"

log_event(log_file,"Writing feather files")

try:
      feather.write_feather(df_adverse_events, file_path_feather_ae)
      feather.write_feather(df_ingredients, file_path_feather_ing)
except Exception as e:
      log_event(log_file, f"Error: {e}")
      sys.exit(0)
```

what user context does python connect with?  Is it the context of the user running the script, be it windows or linux?  How does it pass credentials along?

I ask because I may need to run the script under a windows task scheduler, or a linux CRON job.